# Export and Import Single Azure Data Factory Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am working on a data pipeline on Azure Data Factory. Now, the ADF instance I am using is also being used by other developers working on different projects.

I want to deploy my pipeline on a different Azure tenant. However, I want it to be just my Pipeline that is deployed and not any of the others that belong to the other projects.

How can I achieve this? Of course, all of the Datasets, Linked Services and so on that relate to this Pipeline need to be included as well.

I thought the 'Download support files' option was the way to go, but from what I understand, that is used to provide Microsoft with more context when requesting support.

I am fine with a manual export and import for now. But, would it also be possible to version control just my Pipeline? Note that git has not been configured for the ADF instance I am currently using. I did not think it would be possible to just version control a single Pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use export templates at pipeline level
[image]

for detailed part :
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-data-factory-blog/introducing-azure-data-factory-community-templates/ba-p/3650989